# Increase image_size in WGAN network

Tags: generative-adversarial-network, image-size, loss

I am using WGAN for synthesizing medical images. However, at the moment, Img_size is 64 which is too low resolution.

How can I change the generator and discriminator to make 128*128 high resolution?

Here is my code below.

```
grade =4

dataroot = f"../processed/{grade}/test/"

# Number of workers for dataloader
workers = 2

# Batch size during training
batch_size = 128

# Spatial size of training images. All images will be resized to this
#   size using a transformer.
image_size = 64

# Number of channels in the training images. For color images this is 3
nc = 3

# Size of z latent vector (i.e. size of generator input)
nz = 64

# Size of feature maps in generator
ngf = 64

# Size of feature maps in discriminator
ndf = 64

# Learning rate for optimizers
lr = 0.0002

# Beta1 hyperparam for Adam optimizers
beta1 = 0.5

# Number of GPUs available. Use 0 for CPU mode.
ngpu = 1
```

and Weights_init

```
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, 0.02)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)
```

Generator

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # input is Z, going into a convolution
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(nz, ngf * 16, 2, 1, 0, bias=False), 
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 16),
            nn.ReLU(True), #in-place option = True?
            # state size. (ngf*16) x 2 x 2
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*16, ngf*8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf*8),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*8) x 4 x 4
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*4) x 8 x 8
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*2) x 16 x 16
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf) x 32 x 32
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
            # state size. (nc) x 64 x 64
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input)

# Create the generator
netG = Generator(ngpu).to(device)

# Handle multi-gpu if desired
if (device.type == 'cuda') and (ngpu > 1):
    netG = nn.DataParallel(netG, list(range(ngpu)))

# Apply the weights_init function to randomly initialize all weights
#  to mean=0, stdev=0.2.
netG.apply(weights_init)
```

Discriminator(critic)

```
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # input is (nc) x 64 x 64
            nn.Conv2d(nc, ndf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False), 
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # state size. (ndf) x 32 x 32
            nn.Conv2d(ndf, ndf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # state size. (ndf*2) x 16 x 16
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 2, ndf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # state size. (ndf*4) x 8 x 8
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 4, ndf * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # state size. (ndf*8) x 4 x 4
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False), 
            #nn.Sigmoid() #sigmoid[0, 1]
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input) #feedforward


# Create the Discriminator
netD = Discriminator(ngpu).to(device)

# Handle multi-gpu if desired
if (device.type == 'cuda') and (ngpu > 1):
    netD = nn.DataParallel(netD, list(range(ngpu)))
    
# Apply the weights_init function to randomly initialize all weights
#  to mean=0, stdev=0.2.
netD.apply(weights_init)
```

Here is the training code

```
# Training Loop

# Lists to keep track of progress
img_list = []
G_losses = []
D_losses = []
iters = 0

print("Starting Training Loop...")
# For each epoch
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  # For each batch in the dataloader
  for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0): #enumerate(dataloader, 0)
    ############################
    # (1) Update D network: minimize -E(D(x)) + E(D(G(z))) + lambda_gp*E(|grad(D(y)) - 1|^2)
    ###########################
    ## Train with all-real batch
    netD.zero_grad()
    # Format batch
    real_cpu = data[0].to(device) #data[0] mini batch
    b_size = real_cpu.size(0) #minibatch
    # Forward pass real batch through D
    Dreal = netD(real_cpu).view(-1) 
    # Generate batch of latent vectors
    noise = torch.randn(b_size, nz, 1, 1, device=device) #(b_size, nz, 1, 1)
    # Generate fake image batch with G
    fake = netG(noise) 
    # Calculate the critic for all fake batch
    Dfake = netD(fake.detach()).view(-1) 
    # Calculate loss on all batch
    errD = -Dreal.mean() + Dfake.mean() + lambda_gp * compute_gradient_penalty(real_images=real_cpu, fake_images=fake) #gradient penalty loss function
    errD.backward() 
    D_x = Dreal.mean().item() #D(real data)
    D_G_z1 = Dfake.mean().item() 
    # Update D
    optimizerD.step()
    netG.zero_grad() 
    ############################
    # (2) Update G network: minimize -E(C(G(z)))
    ###########################
    for j in range(g_iters):
        netG.zero_grad()
        fake = netG(noise) 
        # Since we just updated D, perform another forward pass of all-fake batch through D
        output = netD(fake).view(-1) #D(G(z))
        # Calculate G's loss based on this output
        errG = -output.mean() 
        # Calculate gradients for G
        errG.backward() 
        D_G_z2 = output.mean().item() 
        # Update G
        optimizerG.step() 



    # Output training stats
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print('[%d/%d][%d/%d]\tLoss_D: %.4f\tLoss_G: %.4f\tD(x): %.4f\tD(G(z)): %.4f / %.4f'
              % (epoch, num_epochs, i, len(dataloader),
                  errD.item(), errG.item(), D_x, D_G_z1, D_G_z2))
        #print('{}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    
    # Save Losses for plotting later
    G_losses.append(errG.item())
    D_losses.append(errD.item())
    
    # Check how the generator is doing by saving G's output on fixed_noise
    if (iters % 500 == 0) or ((epoch == num_epochs-1) and (i == len(dataloader)-1)):
        with torch.no_grad():
            fake = netG(fixed_noise).detach().cpu()
        img_list.append(vutils.make_grid(fake, padding=0, normalize=True))
        
    iters += 1
```

That was my original code. And I tried to change like this.

```
grade =4

dataroot = f"../processed/{grade}/test/"

# Number of workers for dataloader
workers = 2

# Batch size during training
batch_size = 128

# Spatial size of training images. All images will be resized to this
#   size using a transformer. (originally 64)
image_size = 128

# Number of channels in the training images. For color images this is 3
nc = 3

# Size of z latent vector (i.e. size of generator input)
nz = 64 

# Size of feature maps in generator (originally 64)
ngf = 32

# Size of feature maps in discriminator (originally 64)
ndf = 32

# Learning rate for optimizers
lr = 0.0002

# Beta1 hyperparam for Adam optimizers
beta1 = 0.5

# Number of GPUs available. Use 0 for CPU mode.
ngpu = 1
```

Generator code

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # input is Z, going into a convolution
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(nz, ngf * 32, 2, 1, 0, bias=False), 
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 32),
            nn.ReLU(True), #in-place option = True?
            
            
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*32, ngf*16, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf*16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            
            # state size. (ngf*16) x 2 x 2
            
            
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf*16, ngf*8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf*8),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*8) x 4 x 4
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*4) x 8 x 8
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*2) x 16 x 16
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf) x 32 x 32
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
            # state size. (nc) x 64 x 64
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input)

# Create the generator
netG = Generator(ngpu).to(device)

# Handle multi-gpu if desired
if (device.type == 'cuda') and (ngpu > 1):
    netG = nn.DataParallel(netG, list(range(ngpu)))

# Apply the weights_init function to randomly initialize all weights
#  to mean=0, stdev=0.2.
netG.apply(weights_init)
```

and discriminator

```
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # input is (nc) x 64 x 64
            nn.Conv2d(nc, ndf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False), 
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # state size. (ndf) x 32 x 32
            nn.Conv2d(ndf, ndf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # state size. (ndf*2) x 16 x 16
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 2, ndf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # state size. (ndf*4) x 8 x 8
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 4, ndf * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # state size. (ndf*8) x 4 x 4
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, ndf * 16, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 16),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 16, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False), 
            #nn.Sigmoid() #sigmoid[0, 1]
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input) #feedforward


# Create the Discriminator
netD = Discriminator(ngpu).to(device)

# Handle multi-gpu if desired
if (device.type == 'cuda') and (ngpu > 1):
    netD = nn.DataParallel(netD, list(range(ngpu)))
    
# Apply the weights_init function to randomly initialize all weights
#  to mean=0, stdev=0.2.
netD.apply(weights_init)
```

However, if I change my code like this, while training, Loss_G got positive number while it should be negative number. Therefore, training doesn't work. Here are the outputs. (Loss_D is not going down at all)

```
[0/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 53.7392 Loss_G: 0.1816  D(x): 0.0360    D(G(z)): -0.1816 / -0.1816
[1/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 55.9949 Loss_G: 0.1955  D(x): 0.0360    D(G(z)): -0.1955 / -0.1955
[2/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 66.4417 Loss_G: 0.1168  D(x): 0.0307    D(G(z)): -0.1168 / -0.1168
[3/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 66.9297 Loss_G: 0.2704  D(x): 0.0505    D(G(z)): -0.2704 / -0.2704
[4/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 69.5664 Loss_G: 0.1803  D(x): -0.0246   D(G(z)): -0.1803 / -0.1803
[5/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 65.0955 Loss_G: 0.1722  D(x): 0.0723    D(G(z)): -0.1722 / -0.1722
[6/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 58.5108 Loss_G: 0.2078  D(x): 0.0157    D(G(z)): -0.2078 / -0.2078
[7/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 64.6462 Loss_G: 0.2459  D(x): 0.0378    D(G(z)): -0.2459 / -0.2459
[8/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 64.6244 Loss_G: 0.2015  D(x): 0.0806    D(G(z)): -0.2015 / -0.2015
[9/500][0/10]   Loss_D: 52.2686 Loss_G: 0.1944  D(x): -0.0109   D(G(z)): -0.1944 / -0.1944
[10/500][0/10]  Loss_D: 59.8826 Loss_G: 0.2005  D(x): 0.0591    D(G(z)): -0.2005 / -0.2005
[11/500][0/10]  Loss_D: 56.6620 Loss_G: 0.1919  D(x): -0.0113   D(G(z)): -0.1919 / -0.1919
[12/500][0/10]  Loss_D: 69.9521 Loss_G: 0.1773  D(x): -0.0062   D(G(z)): -0.1773 / -0.1773
```

Thank you for reading my question.